# How to match HTML Entities in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, ckeditor

Hai I am new to CkEditor. I have a requirement in my project preventing CkEditor to 
convert from HTML Entities. `&#123;` and `&#125` are the HTML Entities for open braces and 
curly braces. When i enter entities in the **code view** those html entities are prevent 
to convert curly braces in **editor view(WYSIWYG)**.

The issue here is that, after adding the line in config.js:

```
config.protectedSource.push( /\&\#[12345]/);
```

In Code view:

I entered as:

```
&#123;and&#125;
```

In Editor View i am getting:

```
23;and}
```

But I do not want that one.I want only `and` as output in editor view.

Thanks in advance. If anyone help it is a great appreciation from me

Comment: Your regexp is incorrect: Add a `+` after the character class (the `[12345]` part).

Comment: Now i am getting as output ';and}'.i want only 'and' as ouput

Comment: Then add a `;` to the end of the regexp. I'm not sure about the trailing `}`, though - maybe you need to make the regexp global?

Comment: Okay,';' solved.In my project &#125; converted into '}' this one.directly i pasted my output sorry.now i am getting and&#125

Comment: Then try making the regexp global.

Comment: Thank You Zirak.Your helping is appreciable.It is working fine,at last my reg exp is "/\&\#[1-5]+\;/g"

Comment: @Zirak - add as answer?

Answer (score 0):

the following regex will do what you need:

```
/&#[0-9]+;/g
```

but if you want, you could also catch named entities with this one:

```
/&(#[0-9]+|[a-z]+);/g
```

so `&amp;` would also be caught, for example.